# Add and Remove Foundation Accordion Elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm using the Foundation Accordion in a form and on the 'Add New' button I need to add a new element, then with the 'Remove' button to remove that part of the accordion.

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <li class="accordion-navigation">
        <a href="#panel1">
            <div class="left">
                New Panel
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="panel1" class="content">
            <label name="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title[]">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="right">
    <button class="background-green" id="new"><em class="fa fa-plus"></em> Add New Rank</button>
</div>
```

The Jquery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add New Accordion Element
    var max_fields = 10;
    var i = 1;

    $('#new').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(i < max_fields) {
            i++;
            $('.accordion').append('<li class="accordion-navigation"><a href="#panel' + i + '"><div class="left">New Panel</div><div class="right"><button class="background-red remove"><em class="fa fa-minus"></em> Remove</button></div></a><div id="panel' + i +'" class="content"><label name="title">Title</label><input type="text" name="title[]"></div></li>');
        }
    });

    // Remove Accordion Element
    $('button.remove').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('li.accordion-navigation').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

However, while the add button works, whenever I try to remove an element it fails. Even using console. Log to see if it's recognising the button click doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this jQuery selector instead:

```
// Remove Accordion Element

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li.accordion-navigation').remove();
    i--;
});
```

Which will listen out for newly created buttons (after page load).

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

Also, I would choose to change this line:

`$(this).parents('li.accordion-navigation').remove();`

to this:

`$(this).closest('li').remove();`

`.closest()` performs better looking up ancestors and just looking for `li` or just looking for `.accordion-navigation` will perform better than looking for both `li.accordion-navigation`.

Also, `e.preventDefault()` is redundant here, as your `button` doesn't have any default actions/events attached to it.